# Full local server preparing for use full site backup file from hosting

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, migration, localhost, backups

To install CMS from the beginning locally we need LAMP web service stack. In ex. in our Ubuntu OS, usually in `var/www/html` path will be our site (domain name folder)..
But what from start I have to prepare on my clear OS if: my site was maked and developed on hosting with Cpanel, Softaculous, plugins, themes (some of this instruments or plans on commercial basis - does it have matter?) and etc. and now I want migrate to my home PC? And it is enough just put downloaded backup file into local `html`?

Comment: What is in the backup?  Are all the WordPress files there, or do you need to install Wordpress?  (It could just contain wp-content which is the WordPress uploads directory).   How about the database?  Do you have a database backup included?

Comment: Only OS installed + standart tools (no LAMP, CMS). That what i have inside:
[link](https://yadi.sk/i/AHdjEhFiBTWTUw)

Answer (score 1):

If you do anything short of a full bitcopy of the server disk the answer is going to depend on the specific software you are running.

If you are just worried about the website you typically only need to  back up the HTML directory and a database dump.  However depending on the framework this may require fiddling and manual debugging to deduce required server packages to make it work in another environment. This is the most typical  backup.

A common mid-point might be do record all installed packages on the server (how you dump this depend on IS) and back up this, alongside all databases, HTML directories at the /etc directory.